# cakePHP 2.1 CakeEmail error sending emails array

Tags: arrays, email, cakephp

CakePHP cannot get multiple emails send after a previous execution..
this is an example:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
                $Email->emailFormat('html')
                        ->template('myTemplate')
                        ->to('someEmail@email.com')
                        ->subject('someSubject')
                        ->send('MyMessage');
                 unset($Email);
```

re-Instance cakeEmail

```
$arrEmails = array('email1@email.com','email2@email.com','email3@email.com','email4@email.com','email5@email.com');
$Email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
                $Email->emailFormat('html')
                        ->template('mySecondTemplate')
                        ->to($arrEmails)
                        ->subject('OtherSubject')
                        ->send('MyOtherMessage');
```

I've also tried to create 2 different instances of cakeEmail but the same occur.
Else I've tried is to put in a loop "for" but nothing happens.

If anyone has an idea of ​​what is happening here I would be very helpful and I appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe the issue in more detail? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `reset()` method:

http://api20.cakephp.org/class/cake-email#method-CakeEmailreset